# Echoing to screen when using headers to output to csv

Tags: php, csv, echo

I have a PHP application which generates a set of codes , saves them to MySQL DB and then outputs the same to the user as a downloadable csv file. I also have an echo statement after the code block to convert the PHP array to csv. The echo statement after the convert_to_csv function call instead of outputting to the browser outputs to the file instead and overwrites the first line.  How do I get the echo statement to output to the browser instead?  The code block is below:

```
convert_to_csv($newCodesArray,$fileName,',');
echo "Your file was successfully generated";

function convert_to_csv($input_array, $fileName, $delimiter)
{

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    /* loop through array  */
    foreach ($input_array as $line) {
        /* default php csv handler */
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($f) or die("Can't close php://output");

}
```

Comment: You can't force a download of a file and send text to the screen in the same response. You either return the file (with your CSV-headers) OR you return the text to the screen. One response = one type. Do you really need to tell them that the file was correctly generated? They will probably notice that since the file starts to download.

Comment: The "your file was successfully generated" was just an example. I wanted to print/echo other text as well. Even text like "Your file is being generated. Please wait" before the function gets called.  I have close to half a million rows to output and the user needs to wait for some time so some feedback helps.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Shouldn't the echo be executed before the header is set?

Comment: No, headers must be set before any output is sent to the browser. When you do a echo, all headers will automatically be sent to the browsers. If you try to send headers after, you will get a "Headers already sent"-error.

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined the header as text/csv. So it wont print in the browser as it requires text/html.

Alternatively you can do as following. Copy your function to different file (Ex. csv.php).

```
<?php 
echo "Your file was successfully generated <script> window.location = 'csv.php' </script>";
```

Now it will print your echo string and start download your csv file.

As **Magnus Eriksson** commented,

Above code does not checking its really generated successfully or not. We can extend code with AJAX.

```
    <script>
     $.ajax('csv.php', {
      success: function(data) {
         document.write('Your file was successfully generated.');
         windows.location = 'csv.php';
      },
      error: function() {
         document.write('Your file generation failed.');
      }
     });
   </script>
```

**Note:-** AJAX call will generate file two times.

Comment: The problem with this is that the text _"...successfully generated"_ will always be displayed, even if the file generation fails, so it's not really intuitive...

Comment: Yes. I agree. if we want make condition on successful file, we may require to write more with AJAX instead of redirecting.  we can make condition with return code 200 or error.

Comment: ...your ajax example will run the file generation twice. Once to check if it works, and then again when you redirect the user. That seems like a bad approach.

Comment: ya. that he may need to put conditions on csv.php based on ajax parameters.

Comment: ya correct. this is not optimal solution. two times it will generate.